# How to get function return type's length, precision and scale?

Tags: postgresql, types

I could get the function return type from catalog table like this....

```
SELECT proname, pg_get_function_result(p.oid)
FROM pg_proc p 
JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace 
WHERE n.nspname = 'someschema' and p.proname = 'somefunction'
```

I would also like to get the return type's
a) length
b) precision
c) scale (if supported by the data type)

Is it possible to get it from `pg_catalog` or do I have to take it from `information_schema` columns?

Answer (score 1):

Attention! A precision and scale is usually useless for PostgreSQL scalar functions, because it is ignored. Only type is important.

```
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo1()
RETURNS numeric(10,3) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN 10.0/3.0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 39.511 ms
postgres=# SELECT foo1();
        foo1        
────────────────────
 3.3333333333333333
(1 row)

Time: 0.910 ms
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo2()
RETURNS varchar(2) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN 'abcde';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 28.992 ms
postgres=# SELECT foo2();
 foo2  
───────
 abcde
(1 row)

Time: 0.746 ms
```

Only with domain, you can propagate (or ensure necessary casting) to outer side of function:

```
postgres=# CREATE DOMAIN xx AS numeric(10,3);
CREATE DOMAIN
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo4()
RETURNS xx AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN 10.0/3.0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 32.417 ms
postgres=# SELECT foo4();
 foo4  
───────
 3.333
(1 row)
```

Trick for getting info about used queries to system catalog.

- run psql with parameter -E
- use related \d* command

```
bash-4.1$ psql.92 postgres -E
psql.92 (9.2.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \df
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
      AND n.nspname  'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname  'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
**************************

                                        List of functions
 Schema │            Name            │      Result data type       │ Argument data types │  Type  
────────┼────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────
 public │ f1                         │ void                        │                     │ normal
 public │ foo1                       │ numeric                     │                     │ normal
 public │ foo2                       │ character varying           │                     │ normal
 public │ foo3                       │ numeric                     │ OUT result numeric  │ normal
 public │ foo4                       │ xx                          │                     │ normal
 public │ to_timestamp_ignore_errors │ timestamp without time zone │ text                │ normal
 public │ xavg                       │ bigint                      │ integer             │ normal
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html#.UglOxtJT63M

I've made a short answer base on that article:

```
select
    p.proname, pg_get_function_result(p.oid), 
    p.proargnames,
    array(
        select format_type(a.p::int, null)
        from (select regexp_split_to_table(p.proargtypes::text, ' ') as p) as a
    )
from pg_proc as p 
    inner join pg_namespace as n on n.oid = p.pronamespace 
where n.nspname = 'someschema' and p.proname = 'somefunction'
```

Comment: This query doesn't return any length / precision / scale information